# Connotation of "proud"

Tags: connotation

Does the word *proud* have a bad connotation? I want to use 'proud+something' as a company and website name but I'm not sure what connotation it can have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as pride is one of the [Seven Deadly Sins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins) and was considered to be the pivotal element leading to the downfall of the protagonist in Greek tragedy, you might say it can have negative connotations.

From the Wikipedia article:

> In almost every list, pride (Latin, *superbia*), or *hubris* (Greek), is considered the original and most serious of the seven deadly sins, and the source of the others.

That said, most people use it in a positive way these days. You're probably safe with whatever construction you're contemplating.

Answer (score 7):

I think this really depends on the context, and I can't imagine anyone would misinterpret a line like

> I'm proud of you.

as being something bad. And to connect to your case, it's not very uncommon to see stuff like

> Proud sponsor of ...

and there's nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 4):

If you were to call your company "Proud Office Supplies", it would make me think of a homosexual semi-charity thing, like rainbow-coloured stationary. In general "proud" and "pride" are often associated with groups that feel under-represented in society, like homosexuals, blacks, racists, women—basically any group that traditionally likes to bring it to anyone's attention that they have favourable qualities. This connotation does not apply to any possible name with "proud" in it, but it might; that is something you should consider.

Comment: That is not a connotation which would immediately occur to me.

Comment: @Colin: Really? Not in the name of a company like that? I could only imagine its being used without any hint of this connotation when used with some effort or prize, like "proud creators of" or "proud founder of". I'd not be surprised to find it in something like "proud sponsor of", in which case it draws on this sense of effort, or even parenthood, which really consists in no more than money.

Comment: @Cerberus: Absolutely not. "Gay pride" is an expression I am quite familiar with. "Pride" on its own does not conjure that for me. In fact, if I encountered "Proud Office Supplies" my first thought would be that it was started by somebody called "Proud", who decided to capitalise on their name - as my parents did when they ran "Fine Printing Ltd".

Comment: @Colin: I see. Then perhaps my connotations are not very representative. It could also depend on environment, as we are swamped with all kinds of emancipatory events here. If I ran into a company "Proud Something" I'd wonder "proud of what? what have they done to pride themselves on? ah, it might be something gay, black, etc. etc". But I suppose it isn't like that for everyone. Funny that you should first take it as a last name: did the regular adjective seem logical in that place?

Comment: @Cerberus: I think I would find its primary meaning a little unlikely there, which is why the name occurred to me.

Comment: BTW in this context it's "stationery", not "stationary" - as my mother is fond of saying, "E is for envelopes"...

Comment: @psmears: Ah how stupid, thanks for that! Your mother's phrase "e is for envelopes" looks as though it might work very well.

Comment: Does Cerberus live in San Francisco? :-) If I saw a store named "Proud Office Supplies", my first thought was that they were trying to say that they were proud of the quality or level of service they provide.

Comment: The office supplies store in my town just moved to a new building across the street. I guess they're not a stationary store after all! :-)